# I can not get the latest records in query to influxdb

Tags: javascript, ajax, influxdb, influxql

I have a query in influxql to get cpu, memory, load and disk values ​​with a WHERE clause to indicate that it only brings the data from 1 minute ago. The query works but it always brings the same date, that is, the exact date of the WHERE. I need you to bring me the latest dates, that is, the last time the server sent data to the influexdb database.

What I want is to determine if there are machines that are not sending data, that is, I need the last date that the condiict has:

```
 time> = now () - 1h
```

Now for example I put the date of the WHERE, so:

```
02/02/2019, 19:33:35
02/02/2019, 19:33:35
02/02/2019, 19:33:35
02/02/2019, 19:33:35
02/02/2019, 19:33:35
```

What I need is the last date, because within that hour (1h) there are sure records with a longer date (`time> =`), I mean there must be records with date:

```
02/02/2019, 19:33:35
02/02/2019, 19:35:12
02/02/2019, 19:43:30
02/02/2019, 19:40:25
02/02/2019, 19:36:32
```

I appreciate the help of someone who knows what is happening.
Thank you!

This is the SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
  LAST(cpu_used) AS cpu, 
  LAST(mem_used) AS mem, 
  LAST(load) AS load, 
  LAST(disk_await) AS disk_await 
FROM custom  
WHERE time >= now() - 1m 
GROUP BY hostname
```

This is a complete exit of the query:

name: custom
tags: hostname=linux7
time                          cpu mem load disk
----                          --- --- ---- ----
2019-02-02T18:46:00.42366206Z 1   43  0    0

name: custom
tags: hostname=linux24
time                          cpu mem load disk
----                          --- --- ---- ----
2019-02-02T18:46:00.42366206Z 11  34  0    0

name: custom
tags: hostname=linux4
time                          cpu mem load disk
----                          --- --- ---- ----
2019-02-02T18:46:00.42366206Z 11  42  0    0

name: custom
tags: hostname=linux3
time                          cpu mem load disk
----                          --- --- ---- ----
2019-02-02T18:46:00.42366206Z 73  32  1    0

name: custom
tags: hostname=linux20
time                          cpu mem load disk
----                          --- --- ---- ----
2019-02-02T18:46:00.42366206Z 1   41  0    0

name: custom
tags: hostname=linux1
time                          cpu mem load disk
----                          --- --- ---- ----
2019-02-02T18:46:00.42366206Z 36  55  0    0

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `WHERE` condition, but use only [LAST() InfluxDB selector](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#last).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. If I do not use WHERE, it brings records with very old dates, for example:
name: custom
tags: hostname = linux3
time cpu mem load disk
---- --- --- ---- ----
1970-01-01T00: 00: 00Z 36 55 0 0

Comment: I need the latest records, that is, the most recent ones.

Comment: That is because you are grouping only by `hostname`. For instance 3 records of different time are grouped as one item then how would `influx` knows which `datetime` of the 3 records to use? To group them the `beginning of epoch time` is chosen.